# Cat with gun parallel does not continue as expected

Tags: linux, bash, pipe, cat

Here is my code.

```
file_name="all_parts"
find parts/ -type f > ${file_name}
while read part
    do
        echo processing ${part}
        cat ${part} | parallel -j 100 'wget {} -o logs/wget{%}.log --no-check-certificate -t 2 -w 1 --timeout 20 -O - | aws s3 cp - s3://download/bamboo/extra/{/} && echo {#} >count.txt'
        echo ${part} ok
        rm -rf ${part}
    done < ${file_name}
```

Here is my environment.

```
(py38) $ head all_parts 
parts/segment03
parts/segment04
parts/segment05
parts/segment06
parts/segment07
parts/segment08
parts/segment09
parts/segment10
parts/segment11
parts/segment12
(py38) $ head parts/segment03
https://live.staticflickr.com/7024/6592983699_97d938811c_c.jpg
https://live.staticflickr.com/2749/4259562954_90c98d6969_c.jpg
https://live.staticflickr.com/3054/2559722683_b529ba8040_c.jpg
https://live.staticflickr.com/7407/9952335963_293b119412_c.jpg
https://live.staticflickr.com/1116/617893639_6ab5d13bc8_c.jpg
https://live.staticflickr.com/5346/8755170316_01ce687983_c.jpg
https://live.staticflickr.com/7122/27460712882_bfc7934ce5_c.jpg
https://live.staticflickr.com/6238/6376754433_58c029f20d_c.jpg
https://live.staticflickr.com/5708/31021117812_d58d1ee36b_c.jpg
https://live.staticflickr.com/4029/4229643400_7e23fe8c65_c.jpg
```

Sach segment file has 10,000 lines

My problem is the `echo ${part} ok` never print, and shell hang at first segment file, will not process segment
files one by one.

**Update**: When I type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, the bash continues the process next segment.

**Update2**: Now I split the segment file into 1000 lines per file, then my shell script run very well as my expected.